Lottie with react-native/expo
I download a lottie json file of an animation, but it always gets skewed when rendering the animation.
A colleague of mine downloaded the animation and sent it to me, and that file works out of the box.
I tried a number of different animations, and it always gets skewed.
For instance, this is the animation that I downloaded myself:

While this is the animation that was downloaded by a colleague of mine:

As you can see, the animation that I downloaded has some skewness (like the top 2 samples in the first image). I get the exact same look of an animation when I try to use it in my react-native code.
I see that there are some differences in the downloaded files (too many, cannot make any sense of them).
Is there a difference to what .json animation files are being served for download? If so, how can I also download the ones that are actually working in my react-native project.
Thank you.

I have the same issue at the moment, how did you solve this?
